# I need help with probability of a dice.

Tags: probability

I have no idea how to do this question. If you have a loaded dice such that the probability to obtain an outcome of 1 is 2p/3, the probability of obtaining 2, 3, 4 or 5 is p each, and the probability of obtaining 6 is 3p/2. Find p.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What should the sum of profanities be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Probabilities of all possible outcomes have to add up to a total of $1$.

**UPDATE**

You should have
$$
\begin{split}
1 &= \frac{2p}{3} + 4p + \frac{3p}{2}\\
p &= \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3} + 4 + \frac{3}{2}} = \frac{6}{4+24+9} = \frac{6}{37}.
\end{split}
$$

**UPDATE 2**

So now define a random variable $X$ for the outcome of the die roll, and ask what are the expected value and variance of $X$. You have 6 outcomes, so the expected value is their average, weighted by the probability of the event, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k=1}^6 k \cdot \mathbb{P}[X=k]
$$
Can you write this out and compute it?

As for variance, you have
$$
\mathrm{Var}\ X = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2
$$
where the right term you already computed and the left term is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] = \sum_{k=1}^6 k^2 \cdot \mathbb{P}[X=k]
$$
Could you now complete the computation?

Comment: I'm getting p=6/37, is this correct?

Comment: @Jared yes, see update

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me how to Compute the average outcome of throwing the above loaded dice.
and also Compute the variance in the outcome of throwing the above loaded dice. Even any hints would help me, im lost again.

Comment: @Jared Open a new question for you follow-ups.

Comment: @Jared I added computation of expected value and variance